# php 5.3.2 not throwing exceptions

Tags: php, exception, php-5.3

I'm attempting to throw an exception using php 5.3.2 and it is giving me the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW

I am attempting to throw an exception the following way:

```
throw new Exception('Property ' . $name . ' doesn\'t exist in class Index', '');
```

Edit: I also tried

```
throw new Exception('Property ' . $name . ' doesn\'t exist in class Index');
```

it didn't change the error I was getting.

The complete method:

```
public function __get($name) 
    {
        if(property_exists($this, $name)
            throw new Exception('Property ' . $name . ' doesn\'t exist in class Index');
        return $this->$name;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code before and after the throw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your php code for bloopers, sometimes i miss off a ';' which can cause errors.

also try writing the if statement formally, adding in brackets. i know it shouldn't make any odds but who knows with programming!

Comment: son-of-a-gun, you made you go through the method and realize i left off a paranthesis.. thanks.

Comment: hehe, no problem, if i had a £1 for every time that happened to me, i'd be rich!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing parenthesis of your if() line and so PHP sees this

```
if(property_exists($this, $name) throw new Exception(...);
```

which is not valid syntax. Place a ) at the end of your if() line:

```
if(property_exists($this, $name))
```

*Edit: I hate when I miss the replies below an answer. :(*